# How can I write in CMD text (password) and check if security is on?

Tags: c#, process

I would like to check if State is DISABLED or ENABLED.

I opened the file D:\TOOLS\Security.bat and run it.
In addition i must insert password in CMD to continue program
and I want **to C# write that password**. Is that possible?

[image]

How can I insert password into open process in CMD?

The file must be opened with D:\TOOLS\Security.bat

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\TOOLS\\Security.bat";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.Start();
process.StandardInput.WriteLine("password");
process.StandardInput.Flush();
process.StandardInput.Close();
process.WaitForExit();

Console.WriteLine(process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
```

Here is Security.bat file:

```
runas /user:Administrator c:\utility\info.bat
cls
```

Here is info.bat file:

```
ewfmgr c:
pause
```

When I write password in CMD I got that data.

[image]

From that data I would like to get State value.
But I don not know how to save this console data to string.
How can I **get all data from last console call?**

Here is my code for get state data.

```
string check= @"State(.)*DISABLED";

if (Regex.IsMatch(output, check)) {
   // SECURE IS OFF
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to insert the password into the command prompt.  it's specifically designed to prevent that.

What you CAN do is save the password in the credential cache on that particular machine.  You do this with the `runas` command by using the `/savecred` switch.  After you enter your password, it will no longer ask for it when you runas this app as that user.